# Help me solve two equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've tried unsuccessfully to solve these two problems. I'd grateful for any help here.

1. Differential Equation: $y' = (x^2+2xy-y^2)/(x^2-xy)$

   Here's what I did:
   $$f(\lambda x,\lambda y) = (\lambda ^2x^2+2\lambda ^2xy-\lambda y^2)/(\lambda ^2x^2-\lambda ^2xy) \\ = 
   (\lambda ^2(x^2+2xy-y^2))/(\lambda ^2(x^2-xy)) \\= (x^2+2xy-y^2)/(x^2-xy) = f(x,y)$$

   And I don't know what to do next.
2. Cauchy Equation: $4(2y^3+xy-y)y' = 1, y(0) = 0$

   With this one, I tried moving everything but $y'$ to the right, I also tried moving $4$ to the right and I also tried solving this equation without moving anything and it just doesn't work for me.

I hope you'll be able to help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for the tip, I edited my post

Comment: One question at a time, please.

Answer (score 1):

1)
You proved that the equation is homogeneous
$$y' = \frac {(x^2+2xy-y^2)}{(x^2-xy)}$$
Substitute $y=tx \implies y'=t'x+t$
$$t'x+t=\frac {1+2t-t^2}{1-t}$$
$$t'x=\frac {1+t}{1-t}$$
This equation is separable

$$\int \frac {1-t}{1+t}dt=\int \frac {dx}{x}$$

2)
$$4(2y^3+xy-y)y' = 1, y(0) = 0$$
Consider $x'$ instead of $y'$
$$x'=4(2y^3+xy-y) $$
$$x'-4xy=4(2y^3-y) $$
This equation is a first order linear equation

Use integrating factor or other techniques

Comment: Thanks, You helped a lot

Comment: yw @TomasLuneckas .....